# Prevent Temp Queue auto Topic creation in ActiveMQ

Tags: java, queue, jms, activemq-classic, jms-topic

I have a Rest service that create temp queues on activeMQ for receive
response.

Every request create a temp queue. When I go to Topics list, I view the next:

[image: Topics]

For each temp queue, is created automatically a topic. The principal problem with it, is that topics have a limit for 1,000 topics.

Then, when limit is exceeded, no more messages is accepted from application in ActiveMQ.

Is posible avoid create automatically Topics for each temp queue ?
I have try with tcp://localhost:61616?jms.watchTopicAdvisories=false
Also with connectionFactory.setWatchTopicAdvisories(false); and not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause was not close connections:

Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();

I´ve added:

connection.close();

And not more topics are stored.